# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl with UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

This question has been asked a lot e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494337/partial-curl-modal-transition-style-while-preserving-tool-tab-bar/) but as far as I can see is yet to be answered in full.

I have a `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` as the root vc for one of the tabs, which itself has a `MKMapView` as its root vc. The behaviour I want is for the map to partially curl upwards, **while leaving the tab bar in place** (similar to the Maps app).

So far all I have managed to get working is for the whole view to curl, which isn't as nice.

Solutions I have seen are to set the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to NO, which would make sense however this doesn't seem to work, (unless I am doing something wrong).

For clarity, my code is as follows:

```
MyVC *aView = [MyVC init];
aView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
aView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

For the presenting part, I have tried the two alternatives below, neither of which seem to work:

```
[self presentModalViewController:updateStatus animated:YES];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:updateStatus animated:YES];
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: FYI the init method above is just a static convenience method that does the allocation etc.

Answer (score 4):

I've scoured StackOverflow (and the Internet) for a solution to this problem. The question has been asked many times, but as you note, never sufficiently answered. Many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134311/1148702) give an acceptable solution if it is unimportant whether, e.g., a lower toolbar curls up as well.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001830/mkmapview-half-page-curl/6001933#6001933) have provided a solution using `UIView` animations / CoreAnimation rather than `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` as a modal transition style; this is at worst a solution not allowed in the App Store, and at best is not quite the same effect as one gets from `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` (e.g. the shape of the curl is different).

None of these solutions have provided an answer that mimics Apple's solution in the Maps app (i.e., using `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` but leaving an un-curled `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the screen).

I will continue in this tradition of incomplete answers, since you ask about a `UITabBarController` and my solution doesn't specifically address that case. It does, however, solve the problem I had, which was to get a half page curl with an un-curled toolbar at the bottom.

There must be a more elegant way to do this, but this is how I managed.

The `rootViewController` of my `AppDelegate` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, which I'll call `TAContainerViewController`. `TAContainerViewController` manages a) the actual contents of the screen (the "stuff to be curled"), `TAContentViewController`, and b) the contents "behind" the `TAContentViewController` (e.g. settings), which I'll call `TAUnderCurlViewController`.

My instance of `TAContainerViewController` had properties for a `TAContentViewController` and a `TAUnderCurlViewController`. The `UIView` that was my content was a subview of `TAContentViewController`'s `view` property; likewise what the user sees under the curl is the `view` property of the `TAUnderCurlViewController`.

In the `init` method of `TAContainerViewController` I make sure to do the following:

```
    _underCurlVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

And to curl the contents to reveal under the page, I set up an action that calls this code:

```
    [self.contentVC presentModalViewController:self.underCurlVC animated:YES];`
```

where `self` is the `TAContainerViewController`, `contentVC` is an instance of `TAContentViewController`, and `underCurlVC` is an instance of `TAUnderCurlViewController`.

To dismiss the view, simply `[self.contentVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Some strangeness seems to occur with the frame of `contentVC` when the modal view is dismissed, so I manually reset the frame when the modal view is dismissed.

I've posted a sample project with more details on [Github](https://github.com/timarnold/TAPageCurlDemo). Hopefully someone can take this and turn it into a slightly more elegant solution, or expand it to work with a `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`. I think the trick is to pull the View Controllers out of the well-defined relationships in the Cocoa subclasses, so maybe subclassing those specialty View Controllers would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Arnold's response worked great for me, thanks!

One trap to watch out for: your modal page-curl transition will take over the whole screen if your content view controller is **added as a child of the container view controller**. You could just not add it as a child, but then none of the view lifecycle methods will get called on your content controller (e.g. `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`), which could be a problem.

Fortunately, there is a way around this. In your container controller:

- Add your content controller as a child in `viewDidLoad`
- Remove it as a child in `viewDidAppear`
- Re-add it as a child in `viewWillDisappear`.

That way, your content controller gets its lifecycle methods called, while still being able to do a modal page-curl transition without taking up the whole screen.

Here is the entire code of a bare-bones solution:

```
@interface XXContainerController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *contentController;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL curled;
@end

@implementation XXContainerController

@synthesize contentController = _contentController;
@synthesize curled = _curled;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.contentController = [self.storyboard
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeControllerInStoryboard"];

    // Add content controller as child view controller.
    // This way, it will receive all the view lifecycle events
    [self addChildViewController:self.contentController];
    self.contentController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.contentController.view];
    [self.contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];    
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Remove the content controller as child view controller.
    // This way, the modal page curl transition will
    // not take over the whole screen.
    // NOTE: need to wait until content controller has appeared
    // (which will happen later).
    // Achieve this by running the code at the end of the animation loop
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.contentController removeFromParentViewController];
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Add the content controller as child view controller again
    // so it receives the view lifecycle events
    [self addChildViewController:self.contentController];
}

- (void)setCurled:(BOOL)curled
{
    if (curled == _curled) return;

    _curled = curled;

    // Curl up the content view and show underneath controller's view
    if (curled) {
        // Note you can specify any modal transition in storyboard
        // E.g. page curl, flip horizontal
        [self.contentController
            performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeModalSegueDefinedInStoryboard"
            sender:self];

    // Uncurl and show the content controller's view again
    } else {
        [self.contentController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        // Have to do this, otherwise the content controller's view
        // gets messed up for some reason 
        self.contentController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! One incomplete aspect of my solution is that it doesn't use the proper View Controller Containment APIs.