# How do you keep the toolbar on top like the map app on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, toolbar, page-curl

When the page curl affect takes place, is curling my toolbar as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your toolbar a subview of the view that is being curled away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easily done, unfortunately.  It seems that Apple uses an undocumented mapCurl animation (that we aren't allowed to use).

Tim Arnold has a solution listed [here on stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873903/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-with-uitabbarcontroller/) I tried downloading his example from github, but the project has a few issues (I submitted an issue on github).

What I have done is to just curl the map out of the way and it will display whatever is behind it on the same containing View:

```
- (IBAction)curlMap:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:self.mapCurledUp?UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.mapView cache:YES];
        self.mapCurledUp = !self.mapCurledUp;
        self.mapView.hidden = self.mapCurledUp;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

This doesn't mimic the Maps app exactly, because it doesn't leave the map partially curled, but it close.